# How to find rootProject in Gradle 3.2.1

Tags: java, gradle, user-guide

atm I'm going through the gradle User-Guide at 
https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:dependencies_which_dependencies

I just followed the instructions there and double-, triple- and quadruple-checked what I did, but for some reason I keep running into

```
 Could not set unknown property 'producerMessage' for root project 'messages' of type org.gradle.api.Project.
```

And I can't really figure out what the problem is (same goes for 2 colleagues).

Does someone have some experience here or just realized like "Ohyeah, the problem is ..." ??? Maybe I'm just too blind by now.

My question is basically how do I declare the property on rootProject and how come I can't find that step in the userguide?

settings.gradle

```
include 'consumer', 'producer'
```

consumer/build.gradle

```
task action {
doLast {
    println("Consuming message: ${rootProject.producerMessage}")
}}
```

producer/build.gradle

```
task action {
doLast {
    println "Producing message:"
    rootProject.producerMessage = 'Watch the order of execution.'
}}
```

Comment: could you post your gradle.build files ? seems like you're not setting producerMessage properly

Comment: my gradle.build and settings.gradle files are exactly as shown in the user guide. They are actually copy-pasted

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to declare a variable in the root project before you try to use it in subprojects. So you have to add `build.gradle` file in the folder with `settings.gradle` file and declare this variable within it for example as follows:

```
ext.producerMessage = null
```

It's just a problem with undeclared variable. You can take a look into the [sources](https://github.com/gradle/gradle/blob/master/subprojects/docs/src/samples/userguide/multiproject/dependencies/firstMessages/messages/build.gradle) as well, to see, that it's declared. The problem is that user guide doesn't saym that you need to have one more file with the variable declaration.

Comment: Thanks, that was it! Still wondering why that wasn't in the userguide though

Comment: @Doeyo yes, I don't understand that too, they have a number of examples, which are hard to reproduce from the scratch if you don't know some aspects, which are out of current topic